# How to do IO in tasty test?

Tags: haskell

[Tasty](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/tasty-0.5.1) supports resources, so I can acquire resource, test some data related to this resource (purely) and to release the resource. But how to do some IO actions in my test function?

This is the example from the documentation:

```
import Test.Tasty
import Test.Tasty.HUnit

-- assumed defintions
data Foo
acquire :: IO Foo
release :: Foo -> IO ()
testWithFoo :: Foo -> Assertion
(acquire, release, testWithFoo) = undefined

main = do
  defaultMain $
    withResource acquire release tests

tests :: IO Foo -> TestTree
tests getResource =
  testGroup "Tests"
    [ testCase "x" $ getResource >>= testWithFoo
    ]
```

So my resource is some connection (like socket). And I need to make API call in the `testWithFoo`, so it can not return just `Assertion` but it must be in `IO`. How to do it? Or tasty support only pure tests?

Comment: From looking at the tasty-hunit documentation, `Assertion` is a type synonym for `IO ()`. Meaning you should not have any problem performing impure actions inside of your test. Have you actually tried doing it?

Comment: Oh, true! Yes, passed. That's right answer

Comment: close question OR Erik should make his answer a real answer and mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: @Erik ? (your comment was right)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [tasty-hunit documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/tasty-hunit-0.10.0.1/docs/Test-Tasty-HUnit.html), `Assertion` is a type synonym for `IO ()`.

```
type Assertion = IO ()
```

This means that you can make your API call inside the test without issue.